# Memory leak after shrinkage with realloc

Tags: c, memory-management, segmentation-fault, stack-overflow, valgrind

**I don't know, what has happened to the formatting, but I can't mark selected chunks as code with Ctrl+K. SORRY FOR THAT**

I use gcc with flags as a compiler and run valgrind with:

```
valgrind --leak-check=full -q --error-exitcode=1
```

I am trying ti write a calculator for addition and subtraction. The numbers are stored in an array of the fixed size, written in 10000 numerical system: each element of array has an allocated memory for four digits:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>


#define ELEMENTS 8
#define NUM_INT 4   //Number of digits

typedef struct numb {
    int* digits;
    int how_many;  //How many cells with 4 digits
} numb;


void create(numb** tab) {
    *tab = realloc(*tab, ELEMENTS * sizeof(**tab)); 
    for (int i = 0; i < ELEMENTS; i++) {
        numb cell; 
        cell.digits = calloc(NUM_INT, sizeof (*cell.digits));
        cell.how_many = 1;
        (*tab)[i] = cell; // Put in original array.
     }
     (*tab)[ELEMENTS-2].digits[0] = -1; // Don't bother about the values
     (*tab)[ELEMENTS-1].digits[0] = 1;
}
```

The valgrind shows a problem in two functions:

1. addition of two structures

   ```
    //help function
    int simple_add(int w, int m, int* p) {
        int number;
        int result = w + m + *p;
        if (result >= 10000) {
            *p = division(result);    //division by multiplication while p*i<=10000
            number = result - 10000*(*p);
        } else {
            number = result;
            *p = 0;
        }
        return number;
    }

    //problematic
    void add(numb* a, numb* b) {
        numb *big;
        numb *small;
        if (a->how_many != b->how_many) {
            small = min(a, b);  //simple min and max functions, not written for clarity
            big = max(a, b);
        } else {
            big = a;
            small = b;
        }

        int left = 0;

        int i = 0;
        while (i < small->how_many) {
            big->digits[i] = simple_add(big->digits[i], small->digits[i], &left);
            i++;
        }

        while (left != 0) {
            if (i == big->how_many) { 
                if ((size_t)i*NUM_INT*sizeof(int) >= sizeof(big->digits)) { 
                    int size;
                    if ((size_t)i*NUM_INT*sizeof(int) + 2 >= INT_MAX) size = INT_MAX-1;
                    else size = (size_t)i*NUM_INT*sizeof(int) + 2;
                    big->digits = realloc(big->digits, size);
                }
                big->digits[i++] = left;
                big->how_many++;
                pom = 0;
            } else {
                big->digits[i] = simple_add(big->digits[i], 0, &left);
                i++;
            }
        }
        *a = *big;
    }
   ```
2. set the value to 0

   ```
      void clear(numb* a) {
            a->digits = realloc(a->digits, NUM_INT*sizeof(int));
            a->digits[0] = 0;
            a->how_many = 1;
        }
   ```

For small numbers it works fine for valgrind, without errors. However, as the values in test files get bigger, I get stackovflow/segmentation fault:

I present three types of errors from valgrind to reduce the amount of clutter:

Just before segmenation fault:

```
    Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()                                                                
==13932==    at 0x4837D7B: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:826)                                                            
    ==13932==    by 0x10A084: clear (address)                              
    ==13932==    by 0x10A298: interpreter (in address)                          
    ==13932==    by 0x10A375: game (in address)                            
    ==13932==    by 0x10A436: main (in address)
    
     Address 0x4a3ebc0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 34 free'd                                                
    ==13932==    at 0x4837D7B: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:826)                                                            
    ==13932==    by 0x10A084: clear (in /address)                              
    ==13932==    by 0x10A298: interpreter (in address)                          
    ==13932==    by 0x10A375: game (in /address)                            
    ==13932==    by 0x10A436: main (in /address)                                 
    ==13932==  Block was alloc'd at                                                                                         ==13932==    at 0x4837D7B: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:826)                                                            ==13932==    by 0x10943A: add (in /address)                                  
    ==13932==    by 0x10A1F8: interpreter (in address)                          
    ==13932==    by 0x10A375: game (in address)
    
    Invalid write of size 4                                                                                       
    ==13932==    at 0x10A096: clear (in /address)                              
    ==13932==    by 0x10A298: interpreter (in /address)                          
    ==13932==    by 0x10A375: game (in /address)                            
    ==13932==    by 0x10A436: main (in /address)                                 
    ==13932==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

Mostly this is invalid write or read; invalid free appears only once. I didn't want to clutter the post with the chunk of all messages, but if you need to, I can paste it.

Array from create is freed after the program.

Please, I would appreciate your suggestions. For small numbers it works, thus it is harder for me to track what is going on if we go to big ones. The numbers are supposed to be <INT_MAX

**EDIT**
I have run some tests and have found error in add and clear, but I don't know, how to fix it yet.

Issue:
I have to variables and add the using add()
the first one is zero, thus it has only one cell [0]  ::= num a
the second one is over 10000 (for example: 16547), thus it has two cells [6547][1]   ::= num b

**Where I have found the problem"

1. add b to a; a= 0; b = 16547
2. **clear** a   //supposed to be 0
3. print out b   <- I got an error

   ==52293== Invalid read of size 4
   ==52293==    at 0x10CC75: print_a_number (call5.c:355)
   ==52293==    by 0x10D027: interpreter (call5.c:397)
   ==52293==    by 0x10D35F: rozgrywka (call5.c:453)
   ==52293==    by 0x10D521: main (call5.c:496)
   ==52293==  Address 0x58c6804 is 4 bytes inside a block of size 34 free'd
   ==52293==    at 0x4837D7B: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:826)
   ==52293==    by 0x10CD65: clear (call5.c:367)
   ==52293==    by 0x10D215: interpreter (call5.c:426)
   ==52293==    by 0x10D35F: rozgrywka (call5.c:453)
   ==52293==    by 0x10D521: main (call5.c:496)
   ==52293==  Block was alloc'd at
   ==52293==    at 0x4837D7B: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:826)
   ==52293==    by 0x10B887: add (call5.c:117)
   ==52293==    by 0x10D115: interpreter (call5.c:406)
   ==52293==    by 0x10D35F: game (call5.c:453)
   ==52293==    by 0x10D521: main (call5.c:496)

As we can remember, clear realloced the size and left **the first cell**. However, the other cells are freed. It seems as if the second cell was lost [1], but I do not understand that, if I have assigned the value to the pointer `*a` in add.

Comment: Don't break up the code like that. Just put it all in one single code block. We don't need it to be told like a story - just show the code. That will also probably fix your formatting issues.

Comment: Are you using a C++ compiler for C code? I suggest you don't do that: although similar there are quite subtle (and surprising) differences between the 2 languages. `#ifdef __cplusplus` / `#error bad compiler` / `#endif`

Comment: I don't get why you are using `realloc` (or even `malloc`) when there is a fixed number of `ELEMENTS` (8).

Comment: An array consist of 8 variables; each of them contain a pointer to the array of cells with digits and the length of them may change. If I change the length later woth realloc, I should initialize them with realloc.

Comment: Markdown is bad in lists - to insert code snippet inside a list, indent it "twice" - put __8__ leading spaces.

Comment: In `void create(numb** tab) ` you don't have any `numb` type.

Comment: So what is `numb`? Compile your program with debugging info `-g3` and `valgrind` will show you line numbers! Also try sanitize - compile with `-fsanitize=address` and run your program.  Add `realloc` error checking - I guess that `realloc(big->digits, size);` fails, because `size` is ridiculously high. Why do you use `NUM_INT` everywhere - isn't `how_many` the count of ints? Why use `NUM_INT` then? Add assertions - before each access to `big->digits[i]` add `assert(i >= 0 && i < big->how_many)` . And I doubt there will be much more help without an [MCVE].

Comment: in create - there is `numb cell`

Comment: And what is `int simple add`?  Sadly, you can use whitespace in a filename, but you still can't use it in a function name.

Comment: How many count the number of cells. Each of cell holds up to NUM_INT digits.

Comment: I am deeply sorry for misspelling, but I have had to translate it from my mother tongue.

Comment: Yes, in `create`, you see the expression `numb cell`.  That is a syntax error, as alluded to by @WeatherVane and @KamilCuk, since you typedef's `sth`, but not `numb`.  I suggest you drop the typedef and explicitly use `struct numb`.  The typedef here gives no benefit.

Comment: Once again, I am deeply sorry for any inconsistence due to translation. During translation, I have frogotten, that  have named the struct numb/sth

Comment: Please don't make a moving target by cherry-picking corrections. Please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the shortest *complete* code that shows what you have tried. The best way to do that is by copy/paste.

Comment: I would love to do so, but I have used my native language for variables. It it wasn't too tricky, I can post it